# Why does text within an HTML tag sometimes not get translated?

Tags: google-translate

I've written a program that uses the Google Translate Python API to translate webpages. Most of the time, the API does translation as I expect, but in some cases text within a tag does not get translated.

I tried putting one such tag in the Google Translate web interface and found that the text is still not translated; i.e., the problem has to do with the Google Translate service rather than the way I am using the API.

The specific tag I am looking at is: `<div class="someClass">World:</div>`

I want the word "World" to be translated in the output, regardless of the language into which I am translating. In certain languages, such as French and Khmer, the word "World" is translated as expected, but in other languages, such as Spanish and Somali, it remains "World." I have noticed that removing the class attribute sometimes helps (translation then works in Spanish but not in Somali), and adding more text seems to help as well (I've never seen this issue when the text is a full sentence or paragraph, for example).

In the context of my project, it is particularly important that the case of a tag with just one word inside be handled correctly. Does anyone know why this is happening or how I can make translation happen consistently? A solution requiring minimal to no changes to the original HTML would be ideal.

**Edit** A little more context based on playing around with things: Directly calling `google.cloud.translate.Client().translate('<div class="someClass">World:</div>', 'es')` actually has the correct behavior: "World" becomes "Mundo." I incrementally lengthened the page text by adding tags that came before and after that `div` in the original webpage--none of which wrapped more than one word of text--and the text between tags stopped being translated when the text was around 1,000 characters long. However, when I changed "World:" to a whole sentence, all of the text between tags was translated even when the page text was longer than 1,000 characters.

Comment: How are you calling the translate API with Python? An excerpt of code would be useful. At the moment, I can tell you that the Translate API allows specifying the format of the translated text, with the use of the [`format`](https://cloud.google.com/translate/docs/reference/translate#query-parameters) parameter.

Comment: Sample line: `translated_text = google.cloud.translate.Client().translate(page_text, target_language)["translatedText"]`

I've looked into the format parameter, and it looks like HTML is the default. This is the format I want, because I want to translate the text between tags but not things like attributes within tags themselves.

Comment: Google Translate API will always have some error margin, to which you can minimize in some cases by specifying a `source_language` in the function. I would still recommend you to put the `format` tag, I could see that it's the default tag for the REST call to this API, but I could not see it in the code. As well, if the issue persists, parsing the HTML and translate it will offer [better results](https://www.crummy.com/software/BeautifulSoup/bs4/doc/).